# Дэфолтная база данных в операционной системе

Tags: база-данных

Доброго времени суток! Начал изучать БД и задался вопросом. Чтобы с ними работать необходимо какое-то СУБД аля MySQL, Oracle, Microsoft Access и т.д. Но ведь это всего лишь программы, которые позволяют нам работать с БД, т.е. понимают язык SQL и выполняют нужные команды, но что есть такое сама БД? Это что-то вроде кучи, управляемой области памяти? Что это на уровне компьютера? Где хранятся мои данные. И, если у меня не стоит СУБД, что мне предлагает операционная система? Идет ли с ней вместе какая-нибудь БД (что предлагает microsoft, что macos, что linux)? И опять же, работая с БД через СУБД, когда я хочу посмотреть все базы данных, очевидно, что мне показывается только созданные непосредственно мной, но ведь сама операционная система, какие-то приложения наверняка хранят свои данные. Так вот почему я их не вижу? И вообще одни ли и те же базы данных использует моя операционная система и я?

Comment: Совершенно не обязательно наличие СУБД в ОС. Даже если она там есть, совершенно не обязательно что она будет доступна для простого пользователя. Даже если доступна - не обязательно что юзер сможет подключить к ней свою БД.

Comment: в MySQL базы - это файлы на диске, в моем случае находятся здесь ``C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\data``.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов Это понятно, что наверняка есть какие-нибудь СУБД, доступные только операционной системе, но тут у меня слишком много вопросов. Один из них: если я на macos установлю MySQL, то она будет работать с той же БД, что и в windows? Что вообще такое база данных? Это какие-то данные на жестком диске?

Comment: Вот у вас есть скажем word, он работает с текстовыми документами и хранит их в файлах doc, есть какой нибудь фотошоп, он обрабатывает изображения и хранит их опять же в файлах, скажем psd. А СУБД точно такая же программа, как и все остальные, она хранит информацию, которую ее попросят в файлах своего собственного формата (хотя это могут быть и не файлы, а разделы диска, например). Ее основное назначение уметь получать нужные данные быстро и быть надежной, что бы данные не терялись при сбоях.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нет, [Р]СУБД занимаются не только исполнением SQL (и не все СУБД занимаются этим вообще), обычно они ещё имеют движок хранения данных (и порой не один). Движок может хранить данные в файлах, в памяти, [*не хранить вовсе*](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/blackhole-storage-engine.html) или [хранить с помощью другой БД](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Foreign_data_wrappers).

Файлы БД могут существовать отдельно, но совместимы они обычно только с той СУБД, в которой они были созданы, причём обычно с точностью до версии. Для распространения эти файлы не предназначены.

В условиях сервера БД, доступного по сети множеству клиентов (MySQL, PostgreSQL, Oracle, MSSQL, и т. д.), для переноса данных используется либо **дамп**, либо какой-нибудь сорт **репликации**. Передавать внутренние файлы БД так себе идея: сработать может, но надёжность не гарантируется.

Но БД бывают и *встраиваемые* (H2, SQLite), они обычно предназначены для *монопольного использования единственным клиентом*. В них обычно действуют похожие ограничения по совместимости, но движки таких БД обычно встраиваются прямо в приложения, которые их используют. А раз с приложением распространяется движок хранения данных, можно спокойно поставлять и файл данных для него.

Такие файлы мало смысла распространять как часть дистрибутива ОС. Ядру они однозначно не нужны, а софт "в комплекте", работающий с БД, считать частью ОС довольно спорно.

Так что ОС от них не зависят и не используют их внутри, хотя и могут иметь "для комплекта" компоненты для работы с ними, чтобы облегчить жизнь некоторым приложениям. Установив какую-нибудь СУБД вы не получите доступ ни к каким новым данным.

У самих РСУБД бывают базы данных для внутреннего использования. Скажем, [в PostgreSQL есть базы `template0` и `template1`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/manage-ag-templatedbs.html), которые используются как шаблоны для создания новых баз: `CREATE DATABASE` реально делает клон `template1`. В случаях, когда важно создать **абсолютно пустую** базу, принято клонировать `template0`. Но по умолчанию обе пусты.

Answer (score 3):

Я так понимаю автор не понимает значение словосочетания 'База данных'. Это не какая-то однотипная для системы структура данных, это фактически абстрактное понятие. На [вики](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0_%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85) довольно хорошая статья есть ведь.
Базой данных можно называть по сути какие угодно файлы или иные структуры с данными, а СУБД - это программа, которая умеет оперировать этими данными. Для каждой СУБД своя собственная структура файлов.
У каждой системы есть так же много разных задач, для которых используются внутренние базы данных. Например, в Windows для быстрого поиска файлов по файловой системе строятся индексы для файлов и папок. Это своего рода внутренняя БД, которая управляется каким-то кодом, написанным внутри ОС.

Язык SQL - это лишь некий стандарт для доступа к данным в БД. То есть пользователь СУБД, в какой бы из популярных СУБД он ни работал - он будет писать запросы на одном языке (в общем случае, есть тонкости разумеется). Внутри же каждая СУБД будет парсить этот запрос и осуществлять поиск внутри БД по-разному. На то и расплодилось сейчас так много СУБД и так много споров на тему какую и где лучше использовать.

Сама же структура базы данных может лежать как в одном файле, так и в нескольких, может вообще лежать в памяти, даже одна СУБД умеет хранить данные по-разному, в зависимости от задачи, и пользователь сам настраивает поведение СУБД.

Есть много различных классификаций баз данных, но это отдельная наука.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL, MSSQL, Oracle и т.д. это не интерфейсы для работы с некой абстрактной готовой бд на уровне оси, грубо говоря это и есть сами бд, в каждом случае разные.

Самый распространенный вариант хранения данных в бд - файлы. То есть, в зависимости от реализации, бд может находиться как в одном файле так и во множестве. Есть варианты (к примеру memory таблицы в mysql), при которых данные хранятся в оперативке.

Comment: Ага. Т.е. все же в конце концов - это файлы? Но ведь нельзя утверждать, что без MySQL у меня нет баз данных на локальном компьютере? В той же visual studio entity framework может создать мне БД. Или тут в роли СУБД выступает сам он или VS?

Comment: SQLLite позволяет создавать InMemory базу. И там никаких файлов нет

Comment: VS никак не может создать БД MySQL без MySQL сервера. БД MS SQL, Oracle, Postgree - полностью аналогично

Comment: @JosephKatzman entity framework работает поверх СУБД.

Comment: @JosephKatzman, в VS используется LocalDB для таких случаев. Если точно не знать, то да, утверждать нельзя, любая программа может для своих нужд использовать ту или иную бд, притом развернуть ее локально на твоей машине. Искать такие бд нужно будет ручками. Грубый пример: ты написал приложение, которое создает и использует некую локальную бд, отдал другу, и вот он стал счастливым владельцем бд, даже не зная об этом. (при условии, что у него есть на машине весь необходимый софт)

EF - это orm для облегчение работы с источником данных.

Answer (score 0):

В Windows можно работать с БД Access. Графического интерфейса самого MS Access нет, но компоненты доступа установлены. На Android это SQLLite.

Про "видеть все базы" я не понял вопроса. Зачем это нужно? Каждое приложение работает со своей БД, месторасположение которой ей известно. Этот вопрос похож на "Как скачать интернет?"

Comment: Да, вопрос непонятный, согласен, но вы прочтите мой комментарий под вопросом. Я скорее хотел спросить, будет ли созданная мной ручками БД точно такая же (на физическом уровне или чуть выше), чем созданная операционной системой? Т.е. будет ли это таже база данных, но с другим именем и хранящаяся в другом месте? Или может к системным БД добавляются какие-то метаданные, указывающие, что именно система ее создала?

Comment: Ни система, ни Вы не создаете БД. БД создает СУБД. И вопрос двоичного формата самой базы лежит полностью на СУБД. Если пришел запрос `CREATE DATABASE` создается база и не важно, кто этот запрос выполнил. Двоичная структура может зависеть от кучи параметров: версия сервера БД, файловая система, размер кластера и страницы, поддержки шифрования...

Comment: @JosephKatzman, что значит "таже база данных"? Когда создаешь новую бд - это именно новая бд, даже если она была скопирована со старой. Возможно неверное использование понятия "база данных". Работа бд с файловой системой или другим хранилищем подчиняется правилам оси, которая именно для таких вещей и существует. Если (а я не знаю, сори) существуют некие служебные бд оси, то они в принципе могут работать мимо ядра ос, т.к. были внесены самими разработчиками ос.